# Next.js server that runs nonstop

Tags: next.js, server, backend

I need to make a server, that runs nonstop, so it can check the database data and make an actions based on that, I know, that I can do this with a simple Node.js server, but I was wondering if there is a way to also do this in a Next.js. Just to be clear, I'm not talking about connection between frontend and backend, I know, that I can do that, but when there will be no endpoint called from frontend, the backend is not "running", so it is not able to check the current data from database, to make changes in there. If I understand it correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you are looking for is a background process tool. There are many tools you can use, it depends on your backend configuration. I suggest you to check [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for .Net, [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) for Node.js or any similar.

This tool will execute your services every X time. Hangfire has a dashboard to configure it using [CRON syntax](https://crontab.guru/).

Comment: With the info you gave me I've done some research and I decided to simply use node-schedule for Node.js and every 5 minutes, it is checking the database and doing some actions based on that, as I didn't want to use Bull, because of the Redis requirement, thank you.